# xquery- how to get content of a node which is immediately after a node with known text

Tags: xquery

I am trying to extract content from a XHTML document-- in this document, within a div, there are a number of 'b' elements, each followed by a link.

For eg--

```
<div id="main">
    <b> Bold text 1</b>
    <a href="http://link.com/"> some link 1</a>
      <b> Bold text 2</b>
    <a href="http://link.com/"> some link 2</a>     
    <b> ABRACADABRA</b>
    <a href="http://link.com/"> abracadbralink</a>
</div>
```

Now, I want to extract the link 'abracadabralink'-- the problems are that, I dont know how many  and  elements are there before this specific link-- in different documents there are a different number of such elements- sometimes there are many links immediately after a single  element-- all I do know is that the text for the  element that occurs just before the link that I want, is always fixed.

So the only fixed information is that I want the link immediately after the  element with known text-- how do I get this link using XQuery?

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you are interested in the value of the `@href` attribute? This can be done with standard XPath syntax:

```
doc('yourdoc.xml')//*[. = ' abracadbralink']/@href/string()
```

For more information on XPath, I’d advise you to check out some online tutorials, such as http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp

Comment: I only know the text "abracadabra" that appears just before the link that i want-- again, the "abracadabralink"is only indicative-- eg the link can be <a href="http://xyz.com/"> xyzlink</a>-- only the text "abracadabra" that appears before the link, enclosed in a 'b' element, is known to me...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following should work for you:

```
$yournode/b[. = ' ABRACADABRA']/following-sibling::a/@href/string()
```